# Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment, mapbox

I am trying to put a mapbox in a fragment and it is not inflating. Here is my logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at inscope.inscope.Map.onCreateView(Map.java:33)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/inscope.inscope-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/inscope.inscope-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at inscope.inscope.Map.onCreateView(Map.java:33)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 29 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
03-31 02:37:53.714    1220-1569/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 inscope.inscope/.Main
03-31 02:37:53.774   1220-17998/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-31 02:37:53.785   1220-17998/system_process W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-31 02:37:53.785   1220-17998/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e00f7c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-31 02:37:54.230    1220-1238/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2177629c u0 inscope.inscope/.Main t149 f}
03-31 02:37:55.921    1220-1280/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-31 02:37:55.956  19375-19375/inscope.inscope I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19375 SIG: 9
03-31 02:37:55.978   1220-17998/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa21ea080 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa21faa00
03-31 02:37:56.005    1220-1389/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{21136934 u0 inscope.inscope/inscope.inscope.Main}
03-31 02:37:56.009    1220-1628/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{24af30ca u0 inscope.inscope/inscope.inscope.MainActivity}
03-31 02:37:56.051    1220-1282/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process inscope.inscope (pid 19375) has died
03-31 02:37:56.265    1220-1243/system_process V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{38d8443d u0 Starting inscope.inscope} at 2 of 9 (before Window{21136934 u0 inscope.inscope/inscope.inscope.Main EXITING})
03-31 02:37:56.288    1220-1282/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 19607:inscope.inscope/u0a60 for activity inscope.inscope/.MainActivity
03-31 02:37:56.362  19607-19607/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-31 02:37:56.398  19607-19614/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-31 02:37:56.404      934-934/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 710(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 91% free, 92KB/1116KB, paused 2.537ms total 97.855ms
03-31 02:37:56.398  19607-19614/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
03-31 02:37:56.420  19607-19614/? W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.845ms
03-31 02:37:56.450      934-934/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(208B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 91% free, 92KB/1116KB, paused 1.423ms total 44.264ms
03-31 02:37:56.476  19607-19607/? D/test﹕ before login
03-31 02:37:56.492      934-934/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(160B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 91% free, 92KB/1116KB, paused 24.549ms total 39.827ms
03-31 02:37:56.699  19607-19607/? D/test﹕ set view to login_screen
03-31 02:37:56.821  19607-19631/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-31 02:37:56.825  19607-19607/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3c30, tid 19607
03-31 02:37:56.833  19607-19607/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-31 02:37:56.835    1220-1569/system_process V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{18bdf5 u0 inscope.inscope/inscope.inscope.MainActivity} at 2 of 9 (before Window{38d8443d u0 Starting inscope.inscope})
03-31 02:37:56.852  19607-19619/? I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 347(41KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 32MB/36MB, paused 6.947ms total 71.880ms
03-31 02:37:56.884  19607-19631/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb43fa370, tid 19631
03-31 02:37:56.895  19607-19631/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-31 02:37:56.914  19607-19631/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-31 02:37:56.923  19607-19631/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-31 02:37:56.924  19607-19631/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43b2ae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-31 02:37:57.223    1220-1243/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed inscope.inscope/.MainActivity: +971ms
03-31 02:37:57.226    1220-1372/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 19375 uid 10060
03-31 02:38:22.030    1220-2153/system_process I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 35331(1734KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(173KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 1.285ms total 26.801ms
03-31 02:38:22.086   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ binding HttpService
03-31 02:38:22.086   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps I/GoogleHttpClient﹕ Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
03-31 02:38:22.147   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
03-31 02:38:22.287   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
03-31 02:38:22.404   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ no longer exists, so no auth token.
03-31 02:38:22.549   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
03-31 02:38:22.643   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
03-31 02:38:22.743   1685-19806/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
03-31 02:38:22.885    1685-1696/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:490)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:680)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:806)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.b(SourceFile:770)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:673)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:664)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:332)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:227)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:199)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.UploaderService.a(SourceFile:39)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.af.run(SourceFile:130)
03-31 02:38:27.903    1685-1696/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:490)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:680)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at     com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:806)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.b(SourceFile:770)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:673)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:664)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:332)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:227)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.b.a(SourceFile:199)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.UploaderService.a(SourceFile:39)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.af.run(SourceFile:130)
03-31 02:39:22.017    1685-1685/com.google.process.gapps W/GCM﹕ Heartbeat timeout, GCM connection reset
03-31 02:39:22.041    1220-1372/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ reportBadNetwork(NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]) by 10007
03-31 02:39:22.049    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ ValidatedState{ when=-6ms what=532488 arg1=10007 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
03-31 02:39:22.049    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ DefaultState{ when=-8ms what=532488 arg1=10007 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
03-31 02:39:22.049    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ Forcing reevaluation
03-31 02:39:22.050    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ EvaluatingState{ when=-1ms what=532486 arg1=3 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
03-31 02:39:22.055    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ Checking http://connectivitycheck.android.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
03-31 02:39:22.087    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ isCaptivePortal: ret=204 headers={null=[HTTP/1.1 204 No Content], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Thu, 31 Mar 2016 06:40:08 GMT], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1459406362087], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 204], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1459406362075]}
03-31 02:39:22.087    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ Don't send network conditions - lacking user consent.
03-31 02:39:22.087    1220-1679/system_process D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]﹕ Validated
03-31 02:39:22.089    1220-1276/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ setProvNotificationVisibleIntent: E visible=false networkType=0 extraInfo=null
03-31 02:39:22.090    1220-1276/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Validated NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]
03-31 02:39:31.679   1685-20285/com.google.process.gapps D/GCM﹕ Connected
03-31 02:39:31.719   1685-20285/com.google.process.gapps D/GCM﹕ Message class com.google.e.a.a.q
03-31 02:41:04.560  19607-19614/inscope.inscope W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 15.170ms
03-31 02:44:00.059    1220-1238/system_process I/ProcessStatsService﹕ Prepared write state in 1ms
```

Here is my fragment class:

```
public class Map extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private MapView mapView;

public Map() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            // Set map style
            mapboxMap.setStyleUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);

            // Set the camera's starting position
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679)) // set the camera's center position
                    .zoom(12)  // set the camera's zoom level
                    .tilt(20)  // set the camera's tilt
                    .build();

            // Move the camera to that position
            mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

    });
    return layout;
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="inscope.inscope.Map">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapbox:access_token="my Token" />
```

I have followed the mapbox instructions on their website for gradle and permissions so I'm sure there is nothing wrong with those. It says something is wrong with the "View layout = inflater..." line, except I cant figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: there is class not found exception. I think you missed something from mapbox implementation

Comment: I just posted it. @RaviSravanKumar

Comment: you added mapbox sdk in gradel or as a dependency?

Answer (score 2):

i would like to add a small point to @Tirth Allspark Rami answer.

```
Mapbox.getInstance(this,access_token)
```

should come right after

```
super.onCreate()
```

before assigning any layout to view.

Comment: Would not have guessed this was the problem, probably saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

With the 4.0.0 update that came out yesterday you need to tweak your xml from this, `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView` to `<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView`.

In addition, i'd also like to recommend this [example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/SupportMapFragmentActivity.java) from the test app since you are using the mapview within a fragment.